# Directx9.0 Texture Mapping rendering

Tags: c++, animation, texture-mapping, directx-9

I would like to swap my texture on run-time on my texture (Contain sprite sheet). However, I have problem understand what is rasterizer and I don't know what kind of matrix I should pass in.

```
class CUSTOMVERTEXBEN
{
public:
    FLOAT x, y, z, rhw; // The transformed position for the vertex
    DWORD color;        // The vertex color
`enter code here`FLOAT tu, tv;
};

#define D3DFVF_CUSTOMVERTEX (D3DFVF_XYZRHW|D3DFVF_DIFFUSE|D3DFVF_TEX1)
D3DXMATRIX m_mtxTexture;
D3DXMatrixIdentity(&m_mtxTexture);

m_mtxTexture._41= 1.0f;
m_mtxTexture._42= 1.0f;


g_pd3dDevice->SetStreamSource( 0, g_pVB, 0, sizeof( CUSTOMVERTEX ) );
g_pd3dDevice->SetFVF( D3DFVF_CUSTOMVERTEX );
g_pd3dDevice->SetIndices(g_pIB);

m_mtxTexture._11= 0.f;
m_mtxTexture._12= 0.f;
//m_mtxTexture._33= 1.f;
g_pd3dDevice->SetTexture(0, g_pTexture );  
g_pd3dDevice->SetTextureStageState(0, D3DTSS_TEXTURETRANSFORMFLAGS, D3DTTFF_COUNT2);
g_pd3dDevice->SetTransform(D3DTS_TEXTURE0, &m_mtxTexture);

g_pd3dDevice->DrawIndexedPrimitive( D3DPT_TRIANGLELIST, 0, 0, 4, 0, 2);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using a sprite sheet, you'll want to transform your UV coordinates from one sprite to another. You can do this with a UV transform. You can set transformations for any texture you have currently set (usually texture index 0). See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb206248%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) for more details.

Comment: Hi, Is there link to use their matrix. I am bit confused with D3DTIFF_COUNT2 | COUNT3 | COUNT4. I understand it mean the direction. but if i am using count4 which is xyzw. Does that mean [x1, y1, z1, w1] [x2, y2, z2, w2] [x3, y3, z3, w3] [ transl x, transl y, transl z, transl w]

Comment: You just pass in any D3DX matrix, and transform using any transformation for scale/rotate/translate. If you don't know about matrix math then I can't help you.

Comment: Hi, I understand my matrix. However, when my texture coordinates is not changing that is why i am confused. it's just dont make sense at all. Just want to make that the flag i am settling is correct